# Difficulty to create .txt file from loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, file

I've this data :

```
cat >data1.txt <<'EOF'
2020-01-27-06-00;/dev/hd1;100;/
2020-01-27-12-00;/dev/hd1;100;/
2020-01-27-18-00;/dev/hd1;100;/
2020-01-27-06-00;/dev/hd2;200;/usr
2020-01-27-12-00;/dev/hd2;200;/usr
2020-01-27-18-00;/dev/hd2;200;/usr
EOF

cat >data2.txt <<'EOF'
2020-02-27-06-00;/dev/hd1;120;/
2020-02-27-12-00;/dev/hd1;120;/
2020-02-27-18-00;/dev/hd1;120;/
2020-02-27-06-00;/dev/hd2;230;/usr
2020-02-27-12-00;/dev/hd2;230;/usr
2020-02-27-18-00;/dev/hd2;230;/usr
EOF

cat >data3.txt <<'EOF'
2020-03-27-06-00;/dev/hd1;130;/
2020-03-27-12-00;/dev/hd1;130;/
2020-03-27-18-00;/dev/hd1;130;/
2020-03-27-06-00;/dev/hd2;240;/usr
2020-03-27-12-00;/dev/hd2;240;/usr
2020-03-27-18-00;/dev/hd2;240;/usr
EOF
```

I would like to create a .txt file for each filesystem ( so hd1.txt, hd2.txt, hd3.txt and hd4.txt ) and put in each .txt file the sum of the value from each FS from each dataX.txt. I've some difficulties to explain in english what I want, so here an example of the result wanted

Expected content for the output file `hd1.txt`:

```
2020-01;/dev/hd1;300;/
2020-02;/dev/hd1;360;/
2020-03;/dev/hd1;390:/
```

Expected content for the file `hd2.txt`:

```
2020-01;/dev/hd2;600;/usr
2020-02;/dev/hd2;690;/usr
2020-03;/dev/hd2;720;/usr
```

---

The implementation I've currently tried:

```
for i in $(cat *.txt | awk -F';' '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f3| uniq)
do
    cat *.txt | grep -w $i | awk -F';' -v date="$(cat *.txt | awk -F';' '{print $1}' | cut -d'-' -f-2 | uniq )" '{sum+=$3} END {print date";"$2";"sum}' >> $i

done
```

But it doesn't works...

Can you show me how to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work ? Does it shows an error message, do you have a wrong result, does it go in an infinite loop ? Could you edit your question to add more details ? If it shows wrong data, please include the output in your edit

Comment: You might want `| sort | uniq` instead of just `uniq`. You have iterate over each files anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Because the format seems to be so constant, you can delimit the input with multiple separators and parse it easily in awk:

```
awk -v FS='[;-/]' '
prev != $9 {
    if (length(output)) {
        print output >> fileoutput
    }
    prev = $9
    sum = 0
}
{
    sum += $9
    output = sprintf("%s-%s;/%s/%s;%d;/%s", $1, $2, $7, $8, sum, $11)
    fileoutput = $8 ".txt"
}
END {
    print output >> fileoutput
}
' *.txt
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/CavernousFaithfulFlashdrive) generates:

```
+ cat hd1.txt
2020-01;/dev/hd1;300;/
2020-02;/dev/hd1;360;/
2020-03;/dev/hd1;390;/
+ cat hd2.txt
2020-01;/dev/hd2;600;/usr
2020-02;/dev/hd2;690;/usr
2020-03;/dev/hd2;720;/usr
```

Alternatively, you could `-v FS=';'` and use `split` to split first and second column to extract the year and month and the `hdX` number.

If you seek a bash solution, I suggest you invert the loops - first iterate over files, then over identifiers in second column.

```
for file in *.txt; do
    prev=
    output=
    while IFS=';' read -r date dev num path; do
        hd=$(basename "$dev")
        if [[ "$hd" != "${prev:-}" ]]; then
            if ((${#output})); then
                printf "%s\n" "$output" >> "$fileoutput"
            fi
            sum=0
            prev="$hd"
        fi
        sum=$((sum + num))
        output=$(
            printf "%s;%s;%d;%s" \
            "$(cut -d'-' -f1-2 <<<"$date")" \
            "$dev" "$sum" "$path"
        )
        fileoutput="${hd}.txt"
    done < "$file"
    printf "%s\n" "$output" >> "$fileoutput"
done
```

You could also almost translate awk to bash 1:1 by doing `IFS='-;/'` in while read loop.